# Passing object by reference to a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have a class called Object and a thread called ObjectCreator that manages the creation of an Object. For the sake of simplicity, Object has attributes: objectNumber and objectName.

If I were to create an instance of Object called instance, it would be held by ObjectCreator. Now let's say I needed another thread (let's call it ObjectChanger) to be able to see and manipulate instance; does it make sense to turn instance into a static Object?

I've managed to see results by making instance static so now I can do something like:

```
ObjectCreator.instance.getName();
```

Where getName() is a method of Object. From what I've read from answers to similar questions, static things are evil and there's always workarounds. One suggestion I've read is to pass instance to ObjectChanger as an argument for its constructor but what if instance wasn't created yet at the time I need to create an ObjectChanger?

Perhaps this question is more about OOP concepts than multi-threading or it may be a duplicate so forgive me but I'm quite lost here.

**EDIT:** To address frankie's and Jim's suggestions, here are some code snippets:

**Object:**

class Object

```
{
 private String objectName = "Something";
 private int objectNumber = 1;

 public synchronized void changeNumber(int newNumber)
 {
  objectNumber = newNumber;
 }
}
```

**ObjectCreator:**

```
class ObjectCreator extends Thread
{
 static Object instance;

 public ObjectCreator (Object something)
 {
  instance = something;
 }

 static void createObject()
 {
  ...
 }

 static Object getObject()
 {
  return instance;
 }
}
```

**ObjectChanger:**

```
public class ObjectChanger extends Thread
{
 private Object currentInstance = null;
 private int instanceNumber = null;

 public void run()
 {
  currentInstance = ObjectCreator.getObject(); //If I were to make getObject() non-static, this line churns up an error

  instanceNumber = currentInstance.getObjectNumber();
  currentInstance.changeNumber(2); //valid?
 }
}
```

Comment: Why create a class named `Object` ? `Object` class is already defined in Java and is the superclass of all other classes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I completely forgot about that. I haven't actually created a class called Object. I only named it Object in this question, thinking it would be easier to follow.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the meaning of `static`.  You need to provide more context in the form of existing code and an explanation of your ultimate objective.  It's hard to figure out what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I've added some code snippets. I had cut out a lot of things while trying to retain the meaning of the code but let me know if it's too confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a thread to obtain access to an object not created within it, you must ensure that said thread has a *path* of references which it can follow, leading to the new object.

Consider the following code, with no threads involved.

```
class MyObject { /* ... */ }

interface MyObjectProvider {
    MyObject getMyObject();
}

class Creator implements MyObjectProvider {
    private MyObject obj;
        /* ... */
    @Override
    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        return obj;
    }

    /** Invoked at some point in time. */
    void createMyObject() {
        obj = new MyObject();
    }
}

class Consumer {
    private MyObjectProvider provider;

    Consumer(MyObjectProvider mop) {
        provider = mop;
    }

    void consume() {
        // At some point in time...
        MyObject o = provider.getMyObject();
    }
}
```

Example of a program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Creator creator = new Creator();
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer(creator);

    creator.createMyObject();
    consumer.consume();
}
```

When you add threads to the mix, some code has to change, but the struture is the same.
The idea is to run the Creator in a thread, and the Consumer in another, as you've pointed out.
So, in short, these are the things you should be looking into:

- Concurrency control: look into *data races*, `synchronized`, mutual exclusion, and their friends. [Start here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).
- `wait` and `notify`, if the Consumer should wait for MyObject to be created. [Look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

When you have a nice grasp on these concepts, you may look into the `volatile` keyword (watch out for its pitfalls), and the `java.util.concurrent` package which provides *better* concurrency primitives, concurrent collections, and atomic variables.

Comment: Interesting answer though my knowledge of interfaces is very limited. I think I follow your logic and I'll try to implement it. For now, I've updated my code snippets once more to show that I do have an intention of getting multiple threads to manipulate an instance of Object through a synchronized method. If I were to translate my process into your way of coding, would I need to put the changeNumber() method into an interface as well? Or could I do something like o.changeNumber(2); from the Consumer class?

Comment: Have you got any experience coding in C? If so, think of interfaces as `.h` files. An interface defines a type, same as with classes, and the expected methods for that type. An interface promises that its implementors will define the declared methods, so everywhere you get a reference to an interface type, you don't need to know which concrete class implements it. It is a way to avoid two classes having dependencies on each other (Consumer <-> Creator, in my example). Consumer depends on MyObjectProvider, because it just wants someone to give it objects, it doesn't need specifically a Creator.

Comment: @ScoopsaHaagenDazs I don't think you need any interfaces for the methods in MyObject, leave it be as it is. Are the instances of MyObject going to be used by both threads, after you create them? If not, the methods of MyObject need not be `synchronized`. The method that retrieves the instance of MyObject from the other thread, however, will probably need synchronization.

Comment: Yes I have coded in C and that's clarified quite a number of things in my head. As for the methods in MyObject, I believe I would need to synchronize. Say there's two ObjectChanger threads. If the first ObjectChanger changes an attribute in MyObject, I'd like the second ObjectChanger to be aware of this fact. That seems to fit the criteria you mentioned, at least in my mind. Thanks for your time as well as everyone else that contributed.

Comment: @ScoopsaHaagenDazs If there may be more than one Changer thread, then, yes, by all means, use synchronization in the methods of your Object class.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just make an getter in the ObjectCreator class that retrieves said Object?

ex:  ObjectCreater.getMyObject()

EDIT:

I think you're looking for something like this if Im not mistaken:

```
public class ObjectCreator{
    ArrayList<Object> children;

    public ObjectCreator(){ 
         children = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    //returns back index in children array (for accessing from other threads)
    public int createObject( whatever params here ){
       Object o = new Object( params );
       children.add(o);
       return children.size()-1;
    }

}
```

since I dont know much about the problem you're trying to solve, Im not sure if it has to be thread safe, if you want these objects mapped, or accessed differently, but Im confused where all the confusion about static is coming...

Comment: I've tried this as well, but I appear to be forced to make that method static. Calling ObjectCreator.getMyObject() turns up an error in ObjectChanger

Comment: This is not an answer; it should be a comment.

Comment: Yeah, if you're working around some class constraints you have constructed, its always a good idea to post the code. Its probably forcing you to make the method static because the Object that ObjectCreator is making is also static.  ObjectCreator -- if it holds a member object -- cannot be a static class.  It needs to be instantiated too to have member variables that are accessible by getters.  Does this help?

Comment: My bad, I meant to add it as a comment, but typed it out really fast.

Comment: just edited my answer scoopsa, see if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can put your objects in a list structure like `Vector` and store them in the `ObjectCreator`. Add a getter method to `ObjectCreator` which will accept an index of the object to be received.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a skeleton showing the basic structure.  Error handling is left as an exercise :-)

```
public class MyObject { ... }
...
public class MyObjectCreator { 
    private Map<String,MyObject> createdObjects = new HashMap<>();
    public MyObject makeNewObject(int objNum, String objName)
    {
        MyObject o = new MyObject(objNum, objName);
        this.createdObjects.put(objName,o);
    }
    public MyObject getObject(String objName)
    {
        return this.createdObjects.get(objName);
    }
}
...
public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyObjectCreator oc = new MyObjectCreator();
        MyObject        mo = oc.makeNewObject(10,"aNewObject");
    ...

    MyObject o = oc.get("aNewObject");
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the values of the fields of your class, you should just pass the object into your newly created thread. Then there is really no need to keep a static reference around in a holder class.

But as commented already, we need a bit more information to get to what you want to do with your object and thread.